# Spring boot 2 war repacking

Tags: spring-boot, gradle-plugin

I have a multi project decomposed with the pattern `<feature>/<subfeature>/api` and `<feature>/<subfeature>/implemntation`

I'm using spring-boot-gradle-plugin, in the previous version when the executable war was built the subprojects name jar was updated to reflect the hierarchy. Inside the war libs I had a featureA-subfeatureB-api.jar for example but in the original war I got multiples api.jar.

In spring boot 2, I didn't have the original war and the final war doesn't rewrite the jar names.

For the time being I will rename the folder structure (seems best to me).

Am I missing something else using the new bootWar task and gradle plugin i order to repackage the war as previous version ?

**Update 1 :**
I was not really clear. Sorry
My structure for project 'scooby' is

`root
- application
- featureA
-- api
-- implementation
- featureB
-- api
-- implementation`

Application is a Spring boot application and depends on all the others projects.

With spring-boot-gadle-plugin 1.5, when building the application project, the result was 2 wars (`application-0.0.0.war` and `application-0.0.0.war.original`).

Inside the original/WEB-INF/lib I had 2 `api-0.0.0.jar` and 2 `implementation-0.0.0.jar`

Inside the repackagedWar/WEB-INF/lib I had `scooby.featureA.api-0.0.0.jar`, `scooby.featureA.implementation-0.0.0.jar` and the same for featureB. It was nice :) It was like the baseName was updated by the plugin.

With the same structure and spring boot 2, I only have one war built with multiple `api-0.0.0.jar` inside it.

Today I renamed all my source folders to make them more explicit and make the Jar task use a correct name. I like this better but I was searching the root cause explanation :)

**Update 2 :**

I added 2 github repositories.

- The first one (scooby/ spring boot 1.5.x) : git@github.com:humeurvagabonde/scooby.git
- and the second one (scooby2/2.0-Snapshot) : git@github.com:humeurvagabonde/scooby2.git

With first one : gw clean build produces 2 wars and the jar are renamed but 1 api.jar is still present so I can have duplicate classes (oooh :'( ) ; the second one only 1 war and no renaming

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your description of the behaviour that you were seeing or that you're seeing now. Can you provide a minimal example that illustrates both the old and new behaviour?

Comment: Thank you. I added 2 github repositories. The first one (scooby/ spring boot 1.5.x) : git@github.com:humeurvagabonde/scooby.git and the second one (scooby2/2.0-Snapshot) : git@github.com:humeurvagabonde/scooby2.git With first one : gw clean build produces 2 wars and the jar are renamed but 1 api.jar is still present so I can have duplicate classes (oooh :'( ) ; the second one only 1 war and no renaming.

Answer (score 0):

no connect: git clone git@github.com:humeurvagabonde/scooby2.git
Cloning into 'scooby2'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.